# How can I introduce turbolinks in only one action in a large rails 4.2 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a large legacy rails 4.2 project. I want to start using turbolinks in a single action and then roll it out, one action at a time going forward. However when reading the documentation, it seems like the default behaviour of turbo links is enabled everywhere and disable in specific cases - I would like the opposite behaviour - any suggestions on an approach?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try using the `current_page?` to include turbolinks in the `<head>`
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

kinda like this `if current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout')`

Answer (score 0):

> Note that syntax discussed below is for Turbolinks 5.0.0 and above

Turbolinks can be disabled by adding the data attribute `data-turbolinks="false"`. The effect of this also applies to child elements unless specifically overridden, so you can add it to the `body` tag.

You can then re-enabled Turbolinks via the use of separate application layouts, or a `content_for` block to toggle `data-turbolinks` on and off.

You may also consider overriding specific links with `data-turbolinks="true"` to give you more granular control. Rolling out "one action at a time" is a strange concept as Turbolinks works on the transition of one action to another. Setting it up for a specific set of links allows you to test out and approve specific happy paths, which may be easier to manage.